# Qt 5 connection error on QGLwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I'm trying to connect a signal from a timer to a class I've created, that `inherits QGLWidget`. When I connect it the old way, it works -

```
connect(m_pTickTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
```

But when I try the new way -

```
connect(m_pTickTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &imageDisplay::update);
```

I get a `compilation error` -

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'imageDisplay::connect(QTimer*&, void (QTimer::*)(QTimer::QPrivateSignal), imageDisplay*, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Is it because I don't override the `update()` slot in my class?

Comment: `update` is not a slot, I recommend not to overwrite the method. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @peppe, Thank you very much! It really was just the overloading issue. Now working.